# How to write a nested query with in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Hi all I am new to pandas. I need some help regarding how to write pandas query for my required output.

I want to retrieve output data like 
when 0 < minimum_age < 10 i need to get sum(population) for that 0 to 10 only 
when 10 < minimum_age < 20 i need to get sum(population) for that 10 to 20 only
and then it continues

My Input Data Looks Like:

```
population,minimum_age,maximum_age,gender,zipcode,geo_id 
50,30,34,f,61747,8600000US61747 
5,85,NaN,m,64120,8600000US64120 
1389,10,34,m,95117,8600000US95117  
231,5,60,f,74074,8600000US74074
306,22,24,f,58042,8600000US58042
```

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\Desktop_Folders\Code\Population\population_by_zip_2010.csv")
df2=df1.set_index("geo_id")
df2['sum_population'] = np.where(df2['minimum_age'] < 10,sum(df2['population']),0)
print df2
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but its not getting my retrieved output

Comment: post your code whatever you tried

Comment: More importantly, for this data, some expected output would be nice.

Comment: @Roshan I have posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try pandas cut along with groupby,

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['minimum_age'], bins=np.arange(0,100, 10), right=False)).population.sum().reset_index(name = 'sum of population')

    minimum_age sum of population
0   [0, 10)     231.0
1   [10, 20)    1389.0
2   [20, 30)    306.0
3   [30, 40)    50.0
4   [40, 50)    NaN
5   [50, 60)    NaN
6   [60, 70)    NaN
7   [70, 80)    NaN
8   [80, 90)    5.0
```

Explanation: Pandas cut helps create bins of minimum_age by putting them in groups of 0-10, 10-20 and so on. This is how it looks

```
pd.cut(df['minimum_age'], bins=bins, right=False)

0    [30, 40)
1    [80, 90)
2    [10, 20)
3     [0, 10)
4    [20, 30)
```

Now we use groupby on the output of pd.cut to find sum of population.

Comment: I really appreciate for ur quick ans and time. Thank you so much. Can you just explain me what's your group by query line will be doing which has pd.cut, bins

Comment: I have added some explanation